# Обработка HTML при помощи Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь вытащить ссылки с из HTML и сформировать из них словарь. Я получил список ссылок, но не понимаю, как получить их описание

```
<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.consolelog">Console logs</A>

<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.coredumps">Core dumps</A>
```

Как вытащить ссылки и сформировать из них список разобрался и это прекрасно работает:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
html_links = []

for links in soup.find_all("a"):
    html_links.append(links.get("href"))
```

Но мне необходимо составить словарь, где ключом будет описание ссылки, а значением ссылка:

```
"Console logs": "/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.consolelog"
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение оказалось крайне простым:

```
links = soup.find_all("a")

links_dict = dict()
for i in links:
    links_dict[i.text] = i.attrs["href"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908993/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.text, "html.parser")

text_by_url = dict()

for a in soup.select("a[href]"):
    url = urljoin(rs.url, a["href"])
    text_by_url[a.text] = url

print(text_by_url)
```

---

**PS.**

Выражение `soup.select("a[href]")` вернет теги `<a>`, у которых есть атрибут `href`.

Функция **urljoin** используется для получения абсолютных ссылок из относительных. Другие абсолютные ссылки не будут изменены.